# Java Big O Notation algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o, notation

If anyone could help me with finding the Big O' for the code and please explain it to me.

```
    j = 1; 
    while ( j <= n)
    {
      j = j + 2
    }
```

I know to pick a random n to help see how the loop works out. However, I have my classmates and they say the while(j <= n) executes n/2 times but I just don't see how they came to that answer.

Comment: Just try it for n=10 and n=20. The pattern should become clear.

Comment: Your loop simply runs `n / 2` times, but doesn't mean `O(n/2)` is the correct answer.

Comment: Okay I see it now. Thank you. I was using n = 7 to try to find the pattern. Do you have any advice on how to pick the numbers to find the pattern?

Comment: You don't solve these problems by picking random numbers. You just count the dependencies on *N*. There is one here, and it is linear.

Comment: `O(n/2) == O(n)/2 == O(n)` - linear

Answer (score 0):

When you need to find the asymptotic complexities for any algorithm, always look for the highest order of growth.

Order of growth is the highest power of the polynomial (for a P problem; NP problems are handled differently) for the algorithm. This order will define the complexity.

You have a a while loop, which is a linear loop. Linear means a power/degree of 1
It's linear because if you see the statements executing in the while loop, you can calculate it like this:

Time to execute j=j+2. = C 
No of times loop runs = any integer N

Therefore, the total cost is C*N
Which is polynomial with degree 1
Therefore the complexity is O(N)

Note: It is true that the loop will run n/2 times. That's because you're incrementing j by 2 in every iteration from 1 to 3,5,7 etc. 
The advice is NOT to pick numbers to find the complexity. Use the cost*iterations method mentioned above.

Comment: `No of times loop runs = any integer N`. You cannot just look at the loop condition to decide that this is linear, you need to look figure out how many iterations will be done. In this case it is, but if you did `j = j * 2` it would become sublinear.

Comment: I'm saying that the code will execute in linear time. Even for j= j*2, the code will be executed only n times

Comment: For `j=j*2` there will be only O(log n) iterations.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Forgot j was in the while condition.

Answer (score 0):

Your classmates are *almost* right that the while loop executes n/2 times, but not quite. Try incrementing a counter inside the while loop and then printing it for n = 0 to 9. The correct answer is n/2 + (something involving modulo).

But Big O is not the actual number of executions, it is an *upper bound on the maximum possible* number of executions, and constant factors and lower order terms are ignored. Therefore "/2 + (something involving modulo)" can just be ignored.